# jQuery plugin bind issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, bind, instance

This question refers to my previous question ([jQuery plugin click instance issue & design pattern feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163082/jquery-plugin-click-instance-issue-design-pattern-feedback)). My previous question focuses more on the design approach I use.

I want to bind click events to the element I invoked the script on:

main.js

```
$('nav ul li a.has-sub').sidebarNav();
```

The problem with toggle: **self doesn't return the actual instance, but always the last instance** 
- How to resolve this?

```
toggle : function(){
    console.log(self); // Should return the right instance, but it doesn't!
}
```

In my plugin:

```
_bindEvents : function(){
    self.$elem.bind('click.sidebarNav', self.toggle);
},
```

jquery.sidebarNav.js

```
;(function($){

"use strict";

var SidebarNav = function(element, options){
    this._init(element, options);   
}

SidebarNav.prototype = {
    _init : function(element, options){
        var self = this;
            self.elem = element;
            self.$elem = $(element);
        self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.sidebarNav.defaults, options);
        self._bindEvents();
    },

    _bindEvents : function(){
        self.$elem.bind('click.sidebarNav', self.toggle);
    },

    toggle : function(){
        console.log(self);
    }
}

$.fn.sidebarNav = function(options) {
    return this.each(function(){
        var instance = new SidebarNav(this, options);
        $.data(this, 'sidebarNav', instance);
    });
}

$.fn.sidebarNav.defaults = {}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` instead of `self`. Use `self` when you what to use `this` in a nested function such as `bind` where `this` refers to another object. As I see the `self` variable is not bound to anything in `_bindEvents` or `toggle` functions.
Howerver, if you want to use `self`, declare it as a property of `SidebarNav` by writing `this.self=...` and use it as `console.log(this.self)`.